# Spring Integration Java DSL with Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I am doing a poc with kafka spring integration Java DSL
I am reading a row from data base(DB) and send that row as msg to Kafka Topic. please find the code below.
Code is compiling and i can able to fetch the record from DB, but i didn't see any msg in topic.

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProduceConfig {
 
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingAdapterFlow(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, MyTransformer transformer) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Jpa.inboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory).entityClass(MyRecord.class),                 
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.cron("*/1 * * * * *").maxMessagesPerPoll(1).transactional())
                                  .autoStartup(true))
                .log(message -> "Polled DB Records from KafkaProduceConfig : " + message.getPayload())
                .split()
                .log(message -> "Record after split : " + message.getPayload())
                .enrichHeaders(hrdSpec ->hrdSpec.headerExpression("myRecord", "payload",true))
                .transform(transformer,"getCustomeRecord")
                .enrichHeaders(hrdSpec ->hrdSpec.headerExpression("customeRecord","payload",true))
                .log(message -> "Transformed Record : " + message.getPayload() +",topic :" +message.getHeaders().get("topic"))
                .channel("sendToKafka")
                .get();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundChannelAdapterFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("sendToKafka")
                .log(message -> "outboundChannelAdapterFlow received payload : " + message.getPayload() +",topic :"
                        +message.getHeaders().get("topic")+"key :"+message.getHeaders().get("key"))
                .handle(m->Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(producerFactory()).topic(m.getHeaders().get("topic").toString())
                        .messageKey(m.getHeaders().get("key").toString())
                       // .headerMapper(mapper())
                        .partitionId((Integer) m.getHeaders().get("partitionId")))
                .get();

    }


    public ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory() {
    
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }   
}
```

Msg should publish to Kafka topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration `.handle(m->Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(producerFactory())` is not correct. That lambda makes a new `MessageHandler` which body is just to use that `Kafka` factory whenever a new message arrives. This code just does not handle this message.

You must look into a `handle()` variant where you provide a `MessageHandler` from the factory, not a new by lambda.

So, something like this:

```
        .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(producerFactory())
                    .topic(m -> m.getHeaders().get("topic").toString())
                    .messageKey(m -> m.getHeaders().get("key").toString())
               // .headerMapper(mapper())
                    .partitionId(m -> (Integer) m.getHeaders().get("partitionId")))
```

This way the `MessageHandler` is going to be created during configuration phase. And at runtime its `handleMessage()` method is going to be called against request message. All those option are now lambdas to be called at runtime.

P.S. Please, edit your question for more readable code snippets.

Comment: Hi  Bilan , thanks for you answer i have corrected the message handler , Now  it is giving the error      "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms.   Can you please let me what might be the issue.

Comment: That's absolutely different question. Please, consider to raise a new SO thread with more relevant info. The problem with Spring Integration config has nothing to do with Kafka broker settings.